# Default syntax highlighting isn't for Mathematica on all pages anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Since yesterday, some (but not all!) the questions use the wrong language for syntax highlighting by default.  Here is an example:

- [Which filter does InverseRadon use by default?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/which-filter-does-inverseradon-use-by-default)

> [image]

I can tell that it isn't highlighted as Mathematica because of the different colour scheme, because the comment between `(* ... *)` isn't highlighted, and because the word `from` in the command is rendered in dark blue.

Just to make it clear to people who are not regulars at Mathematica.SE, the Mathematica colour scheme looks like this:

[image]

This problem can be fixed manually by adding `<!-- language: lang-mma -->`, as it has been done in this question:

- [What's the default color function for BarChart, PieChart?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140870/whats-the-default-color-function-for-barchart-piechart)

But this should not be necessary.  The highlighting should always assume Mathematica on this site unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So yeah, funny thing… for technical reasons, a site's tag-to-highlight-language mapping cannot be empty, therefore we had code that just inserted the "default" highlighting for the [default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default) tag if there was no other mapping. The question in question has that tag, and that's why that happened.

I've removed that default mapping, it's not necessary anymore – there is always at least one mapping, from [none](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/none) to "lang-none", to allow `<!-- language: none -->` to work. Yes, that means a question tagged [none](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/none) would have similar issues, but let's wait until that's an actual problem :)

Anyway, this fix will be in the next build.

(Whether or not [default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default) is a good tag in the first place seems questionable to me, but I'll leave that to the community here to decide).